# Angular JS $on "$locationChangeStart" triggered twice when event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to listen to the $on "$locationChangeStart" event in Angular JS and prevent the event from happening under certain circumstances.
As soon as I do event.preventDefault(), the $on "$locationChangeStart" event gets fired again.
Is that a Angular JS Bug?

```
$rootScope.$on "$locationChangeStart", (event, next, current) ->
  if doNotLeave
    event.preventDefault()
```

Thanks in advance,
Steff

Comment: What does event.stopPropagation() do?

Comment: What routing were you using, when this happened?

Comment: Did this ever get solved?

Answer (score 4):

Okey, I've seen a very similar situation and found one possible cause. 
Angular (or our custom route-segment routing, not sure which) will sometimes trim a URL after routing processes it. 
Try logging `next` and `current` and see, what routes exactly you are dealing with. In our case the change was from this `http://wof/Admin#/someRoute` to `http://wof/Admin#/someRoute/` (notice added slash). After we accounted for this - it worked ok.

Comment: Very helful question and answer.  I believe this problem will only occur if you set the hash using native script.  Using the angular $location object never double dips (and always adds the slash).

Comment: Upon further review, I'm not seeing the slash, but rather a double pound sign.

Comment: I am experiencing this same issue exactly as you describe it here. I am wondering what your solution was when you say "once we accounted for that", meaning how did you stop it from adding the slash in the first place?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember the exact solution that we had (or the problem for that matter), but we probably did something like if(next == current + '//'){ do something that prevents the problem}